# Where is the Elasticsearch Plugin API Documentation?

Tags: elasticsearch

The closest thing I've found is their [Elasticsearch Plugins and Integrations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/index.html)
 page, which doesn't help. I was following their out of date tutorial to make a "hello world" plugin, but I can't find any documentation on the classes used. Is there a page with information on what each class does, or do I have to look at the code to figure it out on my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote elastic search developer Adrien Grand([jpountz](https://discuss.elastic.co/users/jpountz)) "No, there is no guide about writing plugins and the API is actually quite unstable. The plugin API is mainly a way for us to provide additional functionality through plugins so that we do not have to fold everything into a single release artifact that would be quite huge. Some community membors have writter plugins by taking inspiration of existing plugins but we do not want to commit on a stable API for plugins as this might prevent us from improving other areas of elasticsearch."

The only real way of learning about developing a plugin is trying to find something similar and modifying it to suite your needs. Developing anything remotely complex will require an extensive knowledge of the ES codebase. I suggest you look into some plugins developed by [jprante](https://github.com/jprante) to get started.

Comment: Clearly, plugin-apis are learned to some extent from examples. However, this is no excuse for skipping documentation. ES is quite a beast already, and requiring potential plugin authors to learn about its plugin endpoints via reverse engineering is not really appealing.